# Arthur C. Clarke on science fiction fans

Tags: arthur-c-clarke, quotes, fans

I once read somewhere that on a science fiction convention Arthur C. Clarke made a comment that science fiction fans are more intelligent than the average person.

Is it true that he said that or is it an urban legend? Is there a source for this?

Comment: True that Clarke said it or true that we **are** more intelligent? :-)

Comment: DO YOU HAVE DOUBTS ABOUT THAT? (of course true that he said it ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's nothing [here](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/authors/a/arthur_c_clarke.html) or [here](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Arthur_C._Clarke) amongst his well known quotes. However, this quote has a similar sentiment:

> One of the biggest roles of science fiction is to prepare people to accept the future without pain and to encourage a flexibility of mind. Politicians should read science fiction, not westerns and detective stories.

Comment: Was dystopian scifi not a thing at the time? It seems to me now that one of the biggest roles of science fiction is to warn people about the possible harmful effects of advances in technology and society.